# Dynamically Populate Listbox - Exclude Empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am creating a form in excel (not a userform) and I am populating the listbox using cells. However, these cells are sometimes A1:10 and sometimes they are A1:A4. Is there a way to dynamically change what is shown in the listbox?

Right now, when I use A1:10 and there are only 4 cells populated, I get the list of 4 populated cells followed by 6 blank entries. I'd like to get rid of the 6 blanks when there are only 4.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is more of a workaround than a solution.  However, it may be able to do what you need it to do.  I've been hitting the same wall you are with trying to make ranges dynamic.

Without seeing some code to know exactly what you're doing, try something like this.

```
Private Sub ListBox1()
    x = 1
    'Add items to listbox until you reach an empty cell.
    Do while Cells(x,1) <> ""
        ListBox1.AddItem Cells(x,1)
    Loop
```

I'm not very familiar with listboxes outside of userforms but this should do approximately what you want to do.

Edit your original post with your code so we can try and get a better understanding of what you've tried and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named range using a dynamic formula. Either of the below formulas will work.

```
=A1:INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH("",$A$1:$A$10,0)-1)

=OFFSET($J$7,0,0,MATCH("",$J$7:$J$32,0)-1)
```

To create the named range, click ctrl+F3 then click new, insert one of the two options above into the "refers to:" section, then label the new range whatever you would like.  in the "row source" section of the listbox simply type in the name you selected for your new named range.